# Why do CQRS command handlers exclude saving UnitOfWork?

Tags: .net, cqrs, mediatr

I've been looking through different `CQRS samples` and most of them use command handlers that do not save `UnitOfWork` (i. e. `DataContext` in case of `Entity Framework`). Something like this:

```
    public void Handle(Command message)
    {
        var course = Mapper.Map<Command, Course>(message);

        _db.Courses.Add(course);
    }
```

Saving (and transaction commit) usually happens in background when request is processed.

I've seen this approach from many leading CQRS guys but I've never heard the reasoning of it.

The biggest problem of this approach are the cases when you need to get an entity Id right after the handler call is returned (which happens quite a lot). There's obviously ways to workaround it (i. e. using Guid, prerequesting unique Id from your database, etc.) but seem clumsy.

But what are the advantages of this approach? Theoretically it could help not to make several database roundtrips in case we have several handlers per request. But it doesn't happen a lot. Another advantage that comes to my mind is that we don't have to type that routine Save call and let it happen automatically. It's kinda nice but does it overweight the Id generation problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do CQRS command handlers exclude saving UnitOfWork?

I think it starts from Evans, [Domain Driven Design](http://a.co/462EAXx), Chapter 6 *The Life Cycle of a Domain Object*.

> There is a raft of techniques for dealing with the technical challenges of database access....
>
> But even so, take note of what has been lost.  We are no longer thinking about concepts in our domain model.  Our code will no be communicating about the business, it will be manipulating the technology of data retrieval.

The idea being that at this point in the code, we are working with the *domain model* rather than looking at the *data model*.

> A REPOSITORY lifts a huge burden from the client, which can now talk to a simple, intention-revealing interface, and ask for what it needs in terms of the  model

Evans is very emphatic about this, in the context of transactions

> *Leave transaction control to the client*.  Although the REPOSITORY will insert into and delete from the database, it will ordinarily not commit anything.  It is tempting to commit after saving, for example, but the client presumably has the context to correctly initiate and commit units of work.  Transaction management will be simpler if the REPOSITORY keeps its hands off.

Some additional notes:

> The biggest problem of this approach are the cases when you need to get an entity Id right after the handler call is returned (which happens quite a lot).

That's usually an indication that you are fighting the wrong problem.  See Marc de Graauw, [Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging).

Comment: I feel like it all makes a little bit more sense with repositories. When we're working with DataContext directly, we're not working with domain, we modify data store. And then we do not make the last step (saving what we modified) and pretend we uncouple domain object manipulation and working with data store.

Answer (score 1):

An important feature of a command handler is that it doesn't return anything (except exceptions). It's a subtle point but if you know all command handlers don't return anything then you can save vast amounts of code and simplify and or make a more robust code base.

But if you are not returning anything then you have the case where you need the id at the start of a process. I think using a GUID is an elegant solution to this.

Pre-fetching unique id's from a database is fraught with problems and I'd avoid that approach if possible.

Here are some advantages:

1. All command handlers will have a common interface
2. Therefore you can write helper code which supports all command handlers. e.g. command routers, security and permission checking, logging, performance monitoring, message queuing ....
3. It can significantly reduce the amount of code you need to write
4. It can significantly reduce the complexity of the code you need to write
5. Testing is much easier and more robust

These are just a few off the top of my head.

Why not include a unit of work?

You could is the short answer. But I like to move the responsibility for persistence out of the handler. The handler may call into it but the actual persistence is done elsewhere (my preference in most cases is in an event store).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would not go as far as calling Guids elegant :)

Comment: Why not? Creating a globally unique id which is database independent. I think that is pretty cool.

Comment: Well... they're ugly :) And if you need to show Guid-based id in url, it never feels right

Comment: Oh yes - in a url they look terrible. But as usual, it depends on the context. Internal app, the business may not care. External SEO friendly website then I would not display them (but there is always an easy workaround).

Comment: What's an easy workaround by the way? Never heard of it.

Comment: I would just generate an id for display in the read model. It can be anything you want it to be. Just part of the normal process.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Honestly some of your points feel a little bit artificial. Like the last one about testing. I don't see how it makes tests easier and more robust. In most cases you have to save your UoW during testing (it's easier than digging through UoW's internals trying to find which status each entity has). But overall you have good points. Thank you!